# TextField condition for Not a pattern

Tags: extjs

i am new to ExtJS .
Consider the declaration of a Textfield below:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id:'lcfirstname',
    name: 'lcfirstname',
    maxLength: 100,
    regex: '/^\s*[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*$/'
}
```

I am able to write a pattern based on the pattern what and all can be typed in text field. but i need to write pattern in the text field such that the text field should not take those pattern
(i.e. **not of regex like that anything is there in EXT JS?**). the pattern can include all the special symbols.

Help needed here!!

Comment: Please either tell `what exactly do you want to allow in textfield?` or `what not`. For e.g. I want user to enter only special characters

Comment: /><;:,."'{}[]`~!@#$%^&*()+=*  for all the symbols. can you tell regex for all symbols , possibly a working fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options to solve this:

- you can use regex:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id:'lcfirstname',
    name: 'lcfirstname',
    maxLength: 100,
    regex: /^(?!.*[a-zA-Z0-9-_])/
}
```

- or you can write a custom validator:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    id:'lcfirstname',
    name: 'lcfirstname',
    maxLength: 100, 
    invalidChars: '[a-z]',
    validator: function(value) {
        var me = this;            
        return new RegExp('^(?!.*' + me.invalidChars + ')' ).test(value);
    }    
}
```

Comment: can you just give regex for all the symbols /><;:,."'{}[]`~!@#$%^&*()+=* shouldn,t be in the textbox

Comment: i got the solution for myself. thanks for your answer. i have accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

first (3) three alphacharachters selected then other last charharters are not including

regex:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{3,}(?!.*[~`@#$%^={}*:;,.<>+?½£|])/
```